# NSCoding Class with Transient Properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, persistence, nscoding

I'm using [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/index.html) / [NSKeyedUnarchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/index.html) along with NSCoding compliant classes to persistently store data in an application.

I'd ideally like to have a few properties within the class which aren't persistently stored *(as there is no need to store that info.)*

Is there a method of doing this with NSCoding?

With Core Data, I know there's Transient Properties, but for NSCoding?

Comment: The only data persisted is what you choose to persist in the `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:` methods.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. Silly me!